# jQuery find checkbox in first td

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many tables and in that I want to do the following,

1. find a table which is present in class.
2. find first tr, first td in a table
3. check checkbox present first td in a table
4. if checkbox present in first td then add class.

---

Below is my code which is not working

```
function myFunction() {
    debugger;
    var FindClass = $("table.Panel");
    debugger;
    var FindClass = $(".Panel table.Table");
    debugger;
    debugger;
    if (FindClass != null) {
        $("#FindClass tr").find("td:first").tagname("input");

    }
}
```

Comment: What is `tagname()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this in 2 achieve this in 2 simple ways...

- 1. Find a table with the class selector. By conditional check we can add the class to the checkbox.
- 2. Implementing the complete code in a single line with out performing the conditional operations.

**HTML**

```
<table class="Panel">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><p>Test</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Second TD</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery (1st method)**

```
if($('table.Panel').length > 0) {
    var tblCheckbox = $('table.Panel tr:first td:first input[type=checkbox]');
    if(tblCheckbox.length > 0) {
        tblCheckbox.addClass('clstochkbox');
    }
}
```

**jQuery (1st method)**

```
$('table.Panel tr:first td:first input[type=checkbox]').addClass('clstochkbox');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/64jv3z6d/

Answer (score 0):

Check for `.length` property as jQuery objects are never `null`. And name it different.

```
var panelTable = $(".Panel table.Table");
if (panelTable.length) {
   // panelTable has elements
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
var chk_box = $("table.Panel tr:first td:first")
                                        .find('input type=["checkbox"]');

if(chk_box.length) {
  $(chk_box.addClass('x')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in also this way.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
    debugger;
    var headerRow = $("table.Panel tr:first th:first");
    debugger;
    if (headerRow != null) {
        var checkbox = headerRow.find("input[type=checkbox]");
        if (checkbox[0].type == 'checkbox') {
            headerRow.addClass('checkboxColumns');

            alert('checkbox Found')
        } else {
            alert('not found')
        }
    }

}

</script>
```